# How to setup Gruntfile.js to watch for SASS (compass) and JS

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm new to using gruntjs and nodejs. I wanted to know how can I setup the gruntfile so that it watches both the sass files and the js files compiles using watch.

This is what I have so far:

```
module.exports = function ( grunt ) {

  "use strict";
  require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    compass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          config: 'config.rb',
          watch: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', []);

};
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) with [grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass). They're both Grunt plugins specifically for this kind of thing:

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'css/build/global.css': 'scss/screen.scss'
            }
        } 
    },


    watch: {

        css: {
            files: ['scss/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass'],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        } 
    },
```

The watch plugin configuration above will watch for changes in any `.scss` files, and will run the `sass` tasked (also defined above). You can even hook into livereload this way. You can also have multiple watches (the above only defines a `css` watch); creating a second watch to minify JS would be easy with [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify)

I have an example you can look at that also concatenates JavaScript and does some minification with grunt-contrib-uglify. [Here is the example](https://github.com/FoodFrom/foodfrom.github.io/blob/master/Gruntfile.js).