# Sass compilation using Grunt and the role of ruby

Tags: ruby, sass, gruntjs

We use Visual Studio 2013 for our development and we need to have .sass files to be compiled to CSS (and do the same as part of build/CI). We are exploring options with Grunt/Gulp.

In the following Urls, there is a mention that we need ruby installed on the machine in order to have Sass (monitor and) compilation using Grunt:

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/get-up-running-grunt/
- http://www.gibedigital.com/blog/2015/may/28/compiling-sass-in-visual-studio-2015/
- http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-grunt-and-sass/

In the following urls, there is no mention of ruby to achieve the same task:

- http://mattwatson.codes/compile-scss-javascript-grunt/
- [How to setup Gruntfile.js to watch for SASS (compass) and JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859082/how-to-setup-gruntfile-js-to-watch-for-sass-compass-and-js)

What is Ruby, and how is that related (if so) to Sass compilation using grunt? Can we not achieve the task without Ruby? If so, advantages/disadvantages.

Comment: Ruby is just another language that Sass uses to compile. It's kind of like how Grunt uses JavaScript/Node.js to run.

Comment: The #1 result if you google "ruby" is the wikipedia page for the Ruby programming language, how did you manage to miss it when you were doing your research?

Comment: I may not be so clear in my question here.  But, I just wanted to know the relation between Ruby programming language, Sass and Grunt.  I am just wondering on why you are focusing narrow/just on "What is Ruby".  That is not what I meant in title/description.

Comment: FYI, Ruby is not needed anymore as Sass was rewritten in Dart and there is Javascript port available, install it with npm: `npm install -g sass` (or `--save-dev` if you don't like globals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby is a programming language; Sass is written is Ruby. So you must have Ruby in order to install and use Sass. You could get away with using Sass without Ruby if you were to use something like http://libsass.org/ (a C implementation of Sass). libsass should be more performant but for a beginner you may want to just stick with regular Sass because the setup is easier.

Those two links don't mention Ruby specifically because they assume you already have Sass setup. They are only explaining how to setup Grunt.